# Node.js REST API Server update with _id attribute

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im trying to update my REST API using _id attribute but nothing happens if I try to use unique _id. It works if I update my entry uisng parametr like room name or room number. Could somebody help me please? Where do I have a mistake? It makes me just crazy!

```
app.put('/api/conferenceRooms/:_id&:_name', (req, res) => {
    var id = req.params._id;
    var name = req.params._name;
    var conferenceRoom = req.body;
    ConferenceRoom.updateConferenceRoom(id, name, conferenceRoom, {}, (err, conferenceRoom) => {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(conferenceRoom);
    });
});


// Update ConferenceRoom
module.exports.updateConferenceRoom = (id, name, conferenceRoom, options, callback) => {
    var query = {_id: id, name:name};
    var update = {
        temperature: conferenceRoom.temperature
    }
    ConferenceRoom.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, callback);
}
```

I checked everything already 1000 times

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are trying to query `_id` with a string of the id, but it is likely type `ObjectId` in MongoDB (default I believe). Try something like:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; 
var query = { _id: new ObjectId(id) };
```

Comment: It doesnt see my id. In ngrok I can see PUT /api/conferenceRooms/&:_IoT                           404 Not Found   when I send https://349349d1.ngrok.io/api/conferenceRooms/:_5a54016c5038c071a3efcd53&:_IoT Headers Content-Type application/json and I add raw body {
 "temperature" : 4
}

Answer (score 0):

Your name is probably undefined or wrong.

change

```
'/api/conferenceRooms/:_id&:_name'
```

To

```
app.put('/api/conferenceRooms/:_id/:_name', (req, res) => {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have the change Url. As now in

```
'/api/conferenceRooms/:_id&:_name'
```

:_id is a Reqest URL Parameter and :_name is Request Query Parameter

What you can do is that you could change both to either Reqest URL or 
 Query Parameter.

When accessing URL Parameter - req.params._id

When accessing Query Parameter - req.query._id

Comment: if I access req.parms_id in ngrok I see PUT /api/conferenceRooms/&:_IoT 404 Not Found   when using req_query._id the same :(